# How do I automatically determine a state given the latitude and longitude / coordinates?

Tags: r, geocoding

I have a data frame of ~17,000 `lat`/`lon` values that I wish to use in order to obtain and populate a new column with the equivalent state.

So far, I have tried several solutions (far too many to list here, but more than ten) that were suggested in other Stack Overflow answers but none have worked for me.

The closest I have come to finding a solution is to use the `ggmap` package, but the problem is that I am warned that I have exceeded the limit, despite only sending a single `lat`/`lon` value to it.

I have individual `lat` and `lon` values and have even combined them into `lat,lon` format too and despite this, none of the aforementioned solutions work for me.

What I want to do is determine the state from a given `lat/lon`/`coord` value and save the state in a new column (`df$state`).

I initially matched all city values in order to obtain the matching state, but the problem there was that as several states contain cities with the same name, the matching process stopped after the first successful match; as a result, I found myself with over 2,800 cities belonging to AK despite them being literally several thousand miles away.

Any suggestions would be great.

Here are the first 100 rows of the `coords`, `lat` and `lon` columns of my data:

```
structure(list(origin_coords = c("31.9618,-83.0588", "44.8782,-69.4718", 
"37.3894,-121.8868", "36.0485,-93.5044", "37.652,-120.7292", 
"33.7942,-84.2018", "32.0749,-81.0883", "31.0286,-97.6115", "40.7559,-111.8967", 
"39.8359,-91.7538", "35.922,-80.537", "39.8036,-75.0058", "43.072,-83.8424", 
"33.5207,-86.8025", "26.1216,-80.1288", "31.9618,-83.0588", "31.9618,-83.0588", 
"61.6303,-149.8181", "33.8687,-84.3351", "42.2196,-88.2426", 
"31.7943,-85.5581", "28.3067,-80.6862", "39.1157,-94.6271", "33.831,-85.7752", 
"39.2655,-76.4935", "32.9824,-87.7919", "61.6303,-149.8181", 
"31.086,-85.7192", "31.9618,-83.0588", "39.9048,-75.2946", "34.1132,-117.3771", 
"41.905,-71.1026", "42.3921,-97.4751", "31.2627,-86.7711", "42.5864,-71.4401", 
"33.7935,-93.807", "39.0097,-123.6523", "61.6303,-149.8181", 
"37.7235,-85.9769", "38.0624,-87.2452", "37.7166,-121.9226", 
"42.9993,-88.2196", "40.6316,-74.0927", "43.0892,-77.436", "39.8359,-91.7538", 
"38.5487,-89.5413", "35.833,-90.6965", "41.363,-89.0008", "37.7953,-95.9368", 
"33.4581,-83.0802", "33.7546,-93.6735", "32.7491,-96.4598", "41.8858,-87.6181", 
"40.7328,-74.0755", "31.2627,-86.7711", "31.9618,-83.0588", "61.6303,-149.8181", 
"38.4642,-85.7775", "40.6344,-92.9219", "37.8366,-89.1424", "42.5648,-83.0701", 
"39.5394,-76.3564", "33.8687,-84.3351", "41.4564,-90.7235", "42.0122,-87.8417", 
"38.8339,-104.8214", "36.4442,-92.5832", "39.838,-104.9988", 
"41.8378,-87.7602", "28.3051,-81.4242", "41.6052,-71.9808", "40.7808,-80.0592", 
"40.5364,-89.1885", "31.9618,-83.0588", "40.8915,-74.0119", "43.2078,-91.2976", 
"34.4574,-83.476", "36.4105,-92.1951", "40.0177,-75.2594", "36.0557,-96.0602", 
"44.694,-85.6763", "61.6303,-149.8181", "40.7446,-73.9345", "29.1989,-82.0874", 
"26.6048,-80.2149", "34.6909,-118.1491", "39.0289,-95.2086", 
"35.4074,-93.1355", "36.2523,-92.6907", "45.2097,-123.2043", 
"37.7953,-95.9368", "61.6303,-149.8181", "39.1157,-94.6271", 
"33.5793,-86.6375", "40.3757,-86.3201", "40.6344,-92.9219", "39.8359,-91.7538", 
"42.3921,-97.4751", "41.2564,-73.2111", "44.2767,-121.1896"), 
    origin_lat = c(31.9618, 44.8782, 37.3894, 36.0485, 37.652, 
    33.7942, 32.0749, 31.0286, 40.7559, 39.8359, 35.922, 39.8036, 
    43.072, 33.5207, 26.1216, 31.9618, 31.9618, 61.6303, 33.8687, 
    42.2196, 31.7943, 28.3067, 39.1157, 33.831, 39.2655, 32.9824, 
    61.6303, 31.086, 31.9618, 39.9048, 34.1132, 41.905, 42.3921, 
    31.2627, 42.5864, 33.7935, 39.0097, 61.6303, 37.7235, 38.0624, 
    37.7166, 42.9993, 40.6316, 43.0892, 39.8359, 38.5487, 35.833, 
    41.363, 37.7953, 33.4581, 33.7546, 32.7491, 41.8858, 40.7328, 
    31.2627, 31.9618, 61.6303, 38.4642, 40.6344, 37.8366, 42.5648, 
    39.5394, 33.8687, 41.4564, 42.0122, 38.8339, 36.4442, 39.838, 
    41.8378, 28.3051, 41.6052, 40.7808, 40.5364, 31.9618, 40.8915, 
    43.2078, 34.4574, 36.4105, 40.0177, 36.0557, 44.694, 61.6303, 
    40.7446, 29.1989, 26.6048, 34.6909, 39.0289, 35.4074, 36.2523, 
    45.2097, 37.7953, 61.6303, 39.1157, 33.5793, 40.3757, 40.6344, 
    39.8359, 42.3921, 41.2564, 44.2767), origin_lon = c(-83.0588, 
    -69.4718, -121.8868, -93.5044, -120.7292, -84.2018, -81.0883, 
    -97.6115, -111.8967, -91.7538, -80.537, -75.0058, -83.8424, 
    -86.8025, -80.1288, -83.0588, -83.0588, -149.8181, -84.3351, 
    -88.2426, -85.5581, -80.6862, -94.6271, -85.7752, -76.4935, 
    -87.7919, -149.8181, -85.7192, -83.0588, -75.2946, -117.3771, 
    -71.1026, -97.4751, -86.7711, -71.4401, -93.807, -123.6523, 
    -149.8181, -85.9769, -87.2452, -121.9226, -88.2196, -74.0927, 
    -77.436, -91.7538, -89.5413, -90.6965, -89.0008, -95.9368, 
    -83.0802, -93.6735, -96.4598, -87.6181, -74.0755, -86.7711, 
    -83.0588, -149.8181, -85.7775, -92.9219, -89.1424, -83.0701, 
    -76.3564, -84.3351, -90.7235, -87.8417, -104.8214, -92.5832, 
    -104.9988, -87.7602, -81.4242, -71.9808, -80.0592, -89.1885, 
    -83.0588, -74.0119, -91.2976, -83.476, -92.1951, -75.2594, 
    -96.0602, -85.6763, -149.8181, -73.9345, -82.0874, -80.2149, 
    -118.1491, -95.2086, -93.1355, -92.6907, -123.2043, -95.9368, 
    -149.8181, -94.6271, -86.6375, -86.3201, -92.9219, -91.7538, 
    -97.4751, -73.2111, -121.1896)), row.names = c(NA, 100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: have you tried this?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43456524/how-to-find-which-polygon-a-point-belong-to-via-sf  (i assume you have got a spatial-object of polygons representing the states?)

Comment: No, I haven't tried that and I'll be honest - if I do have a spatial object, I'm not aware of it.  All I have are coordinates (`lat`/`lon`) and a list of cities.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use function `over` from `sp` package:

```
library(geojsonio)
library(sp)

# get usa polygon data
# http://eric.clst.org/tech/usgeojson/
usa <- geojson_read(
  "http://eric.clst.org/assets/wiki/uploads/Stuff/gz_2010_us_040_00_500k.json", 
  what = "sp"
)

df$state <- NA

# compare points
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  coords <- c(df$origin_lon[i], df$origin_lat[i])
  if(any(is.na(coords))) next
  point <- sp::SpatialPoints(
    matrix(
      coords,
      nrow = 1
    )
  )
  sp::proj4string(point) <- sp::proj4string(usa)
  polygon_check <- sp::over(point, usa)
  df$state[i] <- as.character(polygon_check$NAME)
}

> head(df)
origin_coords origin_lat origin_lon      state
1  31.9618,-83.0588    31.9618   -83.0588    Georgia
2  44.8782,-69.4718    44.8782   -69.4718      Maine
3 37.3894,-121.8868    37.3894  -121.8868 California
4  36.0485,-93.5044    36.0485   -93.5044   Arkansas
5  37.652,-120.7292    37.6520  -120.7292 California
6  33.7942,-84.2018    33.7942   -84.2018    Georgia
```

Comment: Thank you, this works _almost_ perfectly; some of the coordinate values that I have are `NA` (they weren't provided) and as such I am presented with `Error in .local(obj, ...) : NA values in coordinates`; how can I avoid/prevent/skip these?

Comment: @MusTheDataGuy skip the rows with at least one NA value, see my edit to the answer

Answer (score 4):

Here is a sf solution using a spatial join `st_join` of a spatial objects with US-states `states_sf` (created from the USAboundaties package) , and a spatial object containing your data-points `points_sf`.

Please verify the results, since I'm pretty new to spatial work in R.

Just filter the result data.frame for the columns you need.

```
library(sf)
library(USAboundaries)

states_sf <- st_transform( us_states( map_date = NULL, resolution = c("low", "high"), states = NULL), 4326)
points_sf = st_as_sf( points, coords = c("origin_lon", "origin_lat"), crs = 4326, agr = "constant")
result <- as.data.frame( st_join(points_sf, states_sf, join = st_intersects) )


# > head(result)
#       origin_coords statefp  statens    affgeoid geoid stusps       name lsad        aland      awater state_name state_abbr jurisdiction_type                  geometry
# 1  31.9618,-83.0588      13 01705317 0400000US13    13     GA    Georgia   00 149169848456  4741100880    Georgia         GA             state  POINT (-83.0588 31.9618)
# 2  44.8782,-69.4718      23 01779787 0400000US23    23     ME      Maine   00  79885221885 11748755195      Maine         ME             state  POINT (-69.4718 44.8782)
# 3 37.3894,-121.8868      06 01779778 0400000US06    06     CA California   00 403501101370 20466718403 California         CA             state POINT (-121.8868 37.3894)
# 4  36.0485,-93.5044      05 00068085 0400000US05    05     AR   Arkansas   00 134771517596  2960191698   Arkansas         AR             state  POINT (-93.5044 36.0485)
# 5  37.652,-120.7292      06 01779778 0400000US06    06     CA California   00 403501101370 20466718403 California         CA             state  POINT (-120.7292 37.652)
# 6  33.7942,-84.2018      13 01705317 0400000US13    13     GA    Georgia   00 149169848456  4741100880    Georgia         GA             state  POINT (-84.2018 33.7942)
```